# Rails + Sessions: Safe to store partial credit card info in session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I am working on a checkout and I want it so that on the "order summary" page, the user will see their credit card info like `Card Number: ************1111, Expiration Date: 12/15`. I'm not saving the credit card info since that's against standards, so I'm thinking I could save the last 4 digits of the user's credit card info + the expiration date in my session when the user inputs it on the billing information page so that on the "order summary" page it'll show.

Is this against e-commerce standards?

Comment: I definitely wouldn't do it.

Comment: Would you have any ideas of how to persist that data to the next request then?

Comment: I'm assuming you're storing all the information regarding an order in your DB anyways, so why not just make another request to display all that information on that page? That way you avoid storing sensitive information in a session.

EDIT: ie. you submit an order and get redirected to the order summary page after a successful submission and the order summary page has all the info pulled from the database already. make sense?

Comment: I'm not storing any CC information in my database. I'm going through the PayPal Payflow API, so the Paypal manager will have all the data stored there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it. You are allowed to print "Card Number: ************1111" on a piece of paper, and that's permanent and leakable. Hence you are allowed to store *only* those 4 characters in your database, and print them at need.

The expiration date, however, IS sensitive (BC it participates in authorization), so lose it.

(2 years working with payment gateways experience here...)

Comment: Great info! Thanks Phlip